# Customise feincms admin form

Tags: django-forms, django-admin, feincms

I am creating a content from my model using foreign key but I want the object displayed as checkbox or multi select instead of a combo.

Some one told me to use
feincms_item_editor_form 
But I am quite unsure how to use it.

My model is :

```
class TeamMember(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile')
    description = models.TextField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s " % self.name
```

And my content is:

```
class TeamMemberContent(models.Model):
    member = models.ForeignKey(TeamMember)

class Meta:
    abstract = True
def render(self, **kwargs):
    request = kwargs.get('request')
    print request
    return render_to_string('team_member.html', {'members': self.member})
```

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 1):

Actually I just found out using the `ManyToMany` instead of `ForeignKey` solves the whole problem.